# Looping ADODB recordset from Lotusscript do not finish or it return rows in random order

Tags: sql-server, vba, lotus-domino, adodb, lotusscript

I am running an SQL stored procedure using ADODB from Lotusscript in a scheduled  Agent in IBM Domino and get very strange results.

This is the script I run

```
Sub test

    On Error GoTo e 
    Dim sqluser As String,sqlpw As String
    Dim srv As String, database As String, username As String, pw As String, sqlquery As String
    Dim tmp As String,t As Long

    sqlsrv = "..."
    sqldb = "..."
    sqluser = "..."
    sqlpw = "..."

    strConn = |Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Server=| + sqlsrv + |;Database=| + sqldb + |;UID=| + sqluser + |;PWD=| + sqlpw
    Set adoConn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Call adoConn.Open(strConn)
    Set rs = createobject("ADODB.Recordset")
    tmp = |Select ArtGr,KA,Sum(Belopp) Belopp, Sum(Kvantitet) Kvantitet From CrmStatTmp Where Len(KA)>0 Group By ArtGr,KA Order By KA,ArtGr|
    rs.open tmp,adoConn
    rs.MoveFirst
    Do Until rs.eof
        Print "Processing " + CStr(t)
        t = t + 1
        rs.movenext
    Loop

    Set rs = Nothing
    adoConn.close
    Set adoConn = Nothing
    Print "Ready"
    Exit sub
e:

    Print "Error"
    Print Error,Erl
    Set rs = Nothing
    adoConn.close
    Set adoConn = Nothing


End Sub
```

There does not seem to be any errors, the script just seem to stop executing after approx 345, (the number can be different I change the SQL query).

I do not belive there is anything wrong with the SQL query as this is working fine when we try it in other tools.

The image below show how the counter count up to 344 and then suddenly start to count from 326 again. also the script do not seem to get finished as the last line "Ready" is never printed out, and there do not seem to be an error as the print statement in the error handler is never printer out.

I have tried to limit the number of rows returned from the SQL query but that does not help much, at one point I set it to only return the top 20 records and then the counter got to 15 and seem to run the whole script again. so the output was 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,0,1,2...

I have used ADODB in Lotusscript many times and this kind of script have worked many times before.

[image]

How can I change the code to get my script to process all the rows and in correct order

note: some object are declared in another module.

Update:
It gets even more strange if I change the loop to this because this time the scripte runs to the end, but the numbers are still not in sequence

```
Do While Not rs.eof
        Print "Processing=" + CStr(t) + "/Value=" + CStr(rs.fields("ArtGr").value) + "/Status=" + CStr(rs.status) 
        t = t + 1
        rs.movenext
    Loop
```

[image]

Comment: I don't know anything about the Lotus environment but if I saw that behaviour I would assume the code was executing on more than 1 thread or there was more than one process running that code.  Print a message at the top of the sub and see if its invoked more than once.

Comment: the code is only executed once

Comment: You are printing the local variable t++ in a loop, you would not see it change its value out of sequence if a single instance of test() were running

Comment: you are probably right, I wonder how that is possible, I am only executing the code once. maybe some IBM people can answer this one. it is however strange that the script "restart/change" the counter at 344 every time

Comment: Always interesting with these types of problems. As this is LS you could easily debug the code (step through it) to see what happens....

Comment: ... and by the way - does the record returned with the same number contain the same data?

Comment: Dunno what a *scheduled agent* is but could it be running alongside your testing?

Comment: This is very strange. Have you printed data from the records to show whether it is really resetting the position in the result set, or just screwing up the counter t - which is clearly independent of the result set. Have you tried a while loop? In the test where you limited it to the top 20 results, could you try a for loop, or just linear code (i.e.  repeating 20 times: Print "Processing " + CStr(t);  t = t + 1 rs.movenext)?

Comment: I updated the post with a new image

Comment: Ok, just try to throw another print in just after the loop... Should the values of "ArtGr" be unique? Because then it is definitely redoing something for you :-)

Comment: What do you get for rs.recordCount? And come to think of it, how about trying FOR t = 1 to rs.recordCount?

Comment: Also, what happens if you drop the Group By, Order By or both, from the query?

Comment: just noticed that the agent works fine when running it from the Notes client. must be server releated then. the server have 5 agent managers running

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved it, There was no problem looping ADODB, The problem was that the console in Domino Administrator reported the looping as it was processed in the wrong order. Once I instead checked the looping in "Domino Console" it reported the correct order.

don't trust the output you see in Domino Administrator console.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough rep to just write a comment, but if this is a scheduled agent it will run immediately when you make a change to the code and save it - it will then kick off on schedule as well, so could be running twice because of this. Hope that helps.